# Calculating a new column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe of historical election results and want to calculate an additional column that applies a basic math formula for records for winning candidates and copies a value over for the rest of them.

Here is the code I tried:

```
va2 = va1[['contest_id', 'year', 'district', 'office', 'party_code', 
           'pct_vote', 'winner']].drop_duplicates()
va2['vote_waste'] = va2['winner'].map(lambda x: (-.5) + va2['pct_vote'] 
                       if x == 'w' else va2['pct_vote'])
```

This gave me a new column where each row contained the calculation for every row in every row.

Comment: Hi Josh, Could post your input data, result you get and expect? May be masked if sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are operating a element `x` against series `va2['pct_vote']`. What you need is operation on `va2['winner']` and `va2['pct_vote']` element wise. You could use `apply` to achieve that.

consider `a` as `winner` and `b` as `pct_vote`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['a','b','c'])

df
Out[23]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6


df['new'] = df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x : (-0.5)+x[1] if x[0] ==1 else x[1],axis=1)

df
Out[42]: 
   a  b  c  new
0  1  2  3  1.5
1  4  5  6  5.0
```

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.where()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to achieve what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'winner': pd.Series(['w', 'l', 'l', 'w', 'l']),
    'pct_vote': pd.Series([0.4, 0.9, 0.9, 0.4, 0.9]),
    'party_code': pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

---

```
   party_code  pct_vote winner
0          10       0.4      w
1          20       0.9      l
2          30       0.9      l
3          40       0.4      w
4          50       0.9      l
```

---

```
df['vote_waste'] = np.where(
        df['winner'] == 'w', 
        df['pct_vote'] - 0.5,   #if condition is true, use this value
        df['pct_vote']          #if condition is false, use this value
)

print(df)
```

---

```
   party_code  pct_vote winner  vote_waste
0          10       0.4      w        -0.1
1          20       0.9      l         0.9
2          30       0.9      l         0.9
3          40       0.4      w        -0.1
4          50       0.9      l         0.9
```